# embed object for flash is not visible after publishing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, flash

I have a embedded image in an html document like this

```
<div id = "divmarquee" runat="server" visible = "true">
              <object width="475px" height="75px">
                   <embed src="merchant_images/The_Marquee_Deal.swf"      type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="z-index: 0" wmode="transparent" width="475px" height="75px"></embed>
              </object> 
          </div>
```

It was working fine in local computer but when i published to test, the div is shown empty. I don't understand what am i missing. Could someone tell me what it is?

Thanks,
Remo!

Comment: Have you confirmed that your folder structure is the same in test as it is locally, and that the swf file is present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the The_Marquee_Deal_LogoNation.swf file is set as "Content" and is included in your project - otherwise it will not be included during publish. To do this, right click on the file and choose Properties and then set the `Build Action` to `Content`.

Comment: When i right click, i dont find properties at all :( I am new to all this. If you can correct me, it would help.

Comment: Right-clicking on the file in the Solution Explorer from within Visual Studio should show you a properties menu item. If not, just select the file and then press Alt+Enter to switch to the properties.